# Increment the number by 1 whenever i call the funtion in java

Tags: java

I am trying to print the number increment by 1 whenever i call the function, but i am not able to get the solution, below is my code

The blow is the function

```
public class Functions<var> {

    int i=0;

    public int value()
    {

        i++;
        return i;

    }
}
```

I am calling the above function here

```
import Java.Functions;

public class Increment {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Functions EF = new Functions();

        System.out.println(EF.value());    
    }

}
```

Whenever i run the program , i am getting only the output as 1 , but i want the output to be incremented by 1 . Could you please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried return i++;

Comment: use a static variable

Comment: You only call your method once, so how can it be larger than 1?

Comment: You don't even declare `i`…

Comment: @glglgl Since he can run the code, I guess there were things lost in copy&paste ...

Comment: Do you expect your program to maintain state between executions... if so, how ?

Comment: This is because you always create a new object on every run. That objects value is always 0 and gets incremented to 1.

After exiting the main method, your program terminates. If you want to keep the counter over calls of your application, you need to persist the value and read it upon start.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle That won't help with calls in other invocations of the program.

Comment: Copy this line so there are two of them: `System.out.println(EF.value());` Then you will see increment between calls.

Comment: Besides, what do you want to achieve with `Functions<var>`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is with the scope of your variables and your understanding of them. You only call the method once in your given examples, so 1 is arguably the correct answer anyway. Below is a working example which will persist **during runtime** one variable and increment it every time a function is called. Your methods don't seem to follow the common Java patterns, so I'd recommend looking up some small example Hello, World snippets.

```
public class Example{
 int persistedValue = 0; // Defined outside the scope of the method
 public int increment(){
  persistedValue++; // Increment the value by 1
  return persistedValue; // Return the value of which you currently hold
  // return persistedValue++;
 }
}
```

This is due to the scope of "persistedValue". It exists within the class "Example" and so long as you hold that instance of "Example", it will hold a true value to your incremented value.

Test bases as follows:

```
public class TestBases {
 static Example e; // Define the custom made class "Example"
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  e = new Example(); // Initialize "Example" with an instance of said class
  System.out.println(e.increment()); // 1
  System.out.println(e.increment()); // 2
  System.out.println(e.increment()); // 3
 }
}
```

If your desire is out of runtime persistence (the value persisting between application runs) then it would be best to investigate some method of file system saving (especially if this is for your Java practice!)

Comment: Hi Dawson, here you are using three times for System.out.println(e.increment());,

Comment: There should be only one System.out.println(e.increment());
and my output should be incremented by 1 whenever i call the function.

Comment: e.increment() *is* calling the function. The system.out.println's exist purely to show you each step in the process. As I explained in my post, your code is correct, your understanding of how it should work is the problem. Either that, or you aren't explaining your problem correctly.

Comment: I can't comment on other peoples posts as of yet due to my reputation score - but I want to point out that it's definitely **not** a good idea to just static a variable and forget about it. Mayhaps in your scenario, but if you learning then this is detrimental to your education and not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is to increment the number value 1.

But you are calling your function only once. Even though you call the function many times you will get the value 1 only because it is not static variable so it will every time initialize to 0. 
So please check below answer using static context.

Functions.java

```
public class Functions{

    static int i=0;   
    public int value()
    {
        i++;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Increment.java

```
public class Increment{

    public static void main(String []args){

        Functions EF = new Functions();

        System.out.println(EF.value());    
        System.out.println(EF.value());    
        System.out.println(EF.value());    
    }
}
```

Output:

1

2

3

Comment: Got it? Are you need any clarification

Comment: I made the variable as static ,

In your code , you are having the below code three times
     System.out.println(EF.value());    
     System.out.println(EF.value());    
     System.out.println(EF.value());

But in my code,i should have only one time and the output should print the incremented value. Could you please help.

Comment: If you are calling it one time, how can you get the updated code. Thats we are calling three times.

Answer (score 0):

If you design multi-threaded application, it will be better to use AtomicInteger. 
The AtomicInteger class provides you an int variable which can be read and written atomically.

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
```